# Sorting non-alphabetically in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

I want to sort the result of this query

```
select * from candidatelist
```

Which have a column status having only three values Pending, Active and Dormant.

Result of the above query should sort as first showing Pending, then Active and then Dormant, **not alphabetically**. Within each status type, entries should be alphabetically organised.

Table structure

id,name,status

An example

```
2.   Nidheesh      Pending
3.   Rahul         Pending
25.  Hari          Active
1.   Kamal         Active
6.   Heinz         Dormant
```

Like this

Comment: Show your table structure with values

Comment: Well [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/order_by.php) took me 10seconds of searching. So are not able to search by your own or what is the actual problem here?!

Comment: I have the column status. This column has only 3 values Pending,Active and Dormant for every rows. I want to sort with having status Pending first, then Active and then Dormant.

Comment: This is in the close queue but I think it's a great question once I understood the wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you first need custom sorting based on the `status` column and then alphabetically. So first sorting can be done using the `Field()` of MySQL and other ordering is normal. So your query becomes:

```
select * from candidatelist 
order by FIELD(status,'Pending','Active','Dormant'), name
```